# Thoughts on a distribution

Tags: distributions, distribution-identification

I've been having trouble figuring out an appropriate distribution for this data. I wanted to ask for any thoughts. I have percent incidence data (0-100%; not integers) for disease. Using `fitDist` from the `gamlss` package, it thinks the distribution is an `exp` distribution, but when I plot it on a worm plot it's significantly off. When I remove all the zeros, it thinks its a `BCPE` distribution and it fits reasonably well within a worm plot. Could this be zero inflated?

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhQrK.png

Comment: Do you have any associated covariates?  What we're looking at is the marginal distribution of some process, and if there are covariates which are associated with changes in the distribution (e.g. its mean or variance) then we're looking at a mixture of several distributions, which can be hard to model.

Comment: The main covariates will be weather, which is my goal to use for a model. Chiefly, temperature and rain/humidity.

Comment: Because the outcome is between 1 and 100, I would suggest rescaling the data and using a beta regression.  If any observations are 0 or 1 exactly, try a ZOIB model.